# How to break RegexMatcher loop

Tags: flowgear

The first image below is the parent workflow and the image below that is the child workflow. In the child workflow I check if a singular value I provide is in the list separated by commas I also provide. I use a Regex matcher along with an if node to do this. The problem is the Regex matcher continues to execute for all matches although I want it to stop checking @ 2016/05/13 09:08:30, when the expression evaluates to true (the word 'Contract' is present in 'Contract,VMS,Payroll'). I want the Regex matcher to stop and then output isTrue boolean to the variable bar so the parent workflow gets a 'true' instead of the false which it gets now. (which you can see happens in the last activity entry 2016/05/13 09:08:30 where Value is false (since it gets the LAST updated value) for the child workflow).

[image: Main Parent Workflow]
[image: Child Workflow: If its not any of them]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm..... There isn't a way to break out of that loop but you should be able to use Regex Match One instead of the loop version as you're actually only interested in determining whether a given pattern matches rather than needing to iterate over each match in order to process it further.

Comment: Oh maybe if I use a Regex like this: ,?({EMPLOYEE TYPE GOES HERE}),? I just extract the isTrue variable from the Regex Match One node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes or if its really just s simple string match, use the If Node with expression 'Value like "*matchexpression*" '